# Método post guarda repetidos Retrofit

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, retrofit, http-post

Tengo una función que envía un objeto a una api por medio de un metodo POST usando retrofit, al enviarse la info valida si ya existe o no, de ser así muestra un AlertDialog al usuario para que decida si quiere guardarlo repetido (así lo necesito), el problema es que cuando le doy click en ok (para que guarde el registro repetido) lo guarda 2 o 3 veces seguidas.
Aquí mi codigo:

```
private fun peticionPost() {
  if (validacion()) {
    val post = Model(               
      codigoTxt.text.toString(),
      nombreTxt.text.toString(),
      telefonoTxt.text.toString(),
      nacionalidadTxt.text.toString(),
      edadTxt.text.toString().toInt()
      )
      
      viewModel.post("revisar",post)
      viewModel.mymodelpost.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
      response.clone().enqueue(object : Callback<Model> {
      override fun onFailure(call: Call<Model>, t: Throwable) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Error: " + t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Model>, response: Response<Model>)         {
          if (response.isSuccessful) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Datos enviados correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() 

          } else {
          //alert si la solicitud ya existe
          if(response.errorBody()!!.string()=="La solicitud ya existe") 
          {
          val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity!!)
          val alert = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, null)
          builder.setView(alert)
          val dialog = builder.create()
          dialog.show()

          val ok=alert.findViewById<Button>(R.id.ok_button)
          val cancel=alert.findViewById<Button>(R.id.cancel_button)

          ok.setOnClickListener(){
          viewModel.post("repetido",post)
          viewModel.mymodelpost.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
          response.clone().enqueue(object : Callback<ProdMuestreo> { override fun onFailure(call: Call<ProdMuestreo>, t: Throwable) {
          Toast.makeText(activity, "Error: " + t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
          }
          override fun onResponse(call: Call<ProdMuestreo>, response: Response<ProdMuestreo>) {
          if (response.isSuccessful) {
          Toast.makeText(activity,"Datos enviados correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()   
          } else {
          Log.d("Main", response.errorBody().toString())
          Log.d("Main", response.code().toString())
          Log.d("Main", response.errorBody().toString())
          Toast.makeText(activity,  response.errorBody()!!.string(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
          }
          }
          })
          })
          dialog.hide()
          }
          
          cancel.setOnClickListener() {
          dialog.hide()
          }
          }
          else {
          Toast.makeText(activity,  response.errorBody()!!.string(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
          }
          }
         }
       })
     })
   }
}
```

ViewModel

```html
class ViewModel (private val repository: Repository): ViewModel() {
val model:MutableLiveData<Call<MyModel>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun post(param: String, post:MyModel) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val response=repository.post(param, post)
            model.value=response
        }
    }
}
```

MainViewModelFactory

```html
class MainViewModelFactory ( private val repository:Repository): ViewModelProvider.Factory{

    override fun <T : androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return ViewModel(repository) as T
    }
}
```

Repository

```html
class Repository {
    fun post(param: String, post: MyModel): Call<MyModel> {
        return RetroInstance.api.post(param, post)
    }
}
```

RetroInstance

```html
object RetroInstance{
    private val retrofit by lazy{
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    val api : IApiService by lazy{
        retrofit.create(IApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

Interface API

```html
interface IApiService {
@POST("myAction/{param}")
  fun post(@Path("param") param: String, @Body post:MyModel): Call<MyModel>
}
```

Comment: ¿Revisaste lo que está ocurriendo en el `ViewModel`?

Comment: @A.Cedano hola he añadido mas código para que pueda ser mas claro